Incremental materialized view - workaround to query table more than once
I need to create incremental materialized view for reporting purposes having the following source table:



product
date
subprduct
sector




A
2024-01-01
AA
X


A
2024-01-01
AA
X


A
2024-01-01
AB
Y


A
2024-01-02
AA
X


B
2024-01-01
AA
X


B
2024-01-01
AB
X


B
2024-01-01
AB
Y


B
2024-01-01
AB
Y


B
2024-01-02
AA
X


B
2024-01-02
AA
Y


C
2024-01-02
AA
X


C
2024-01-02
AA
X



The aggregated result should be the following:



product
date
subproduct
count




A
2024-01-01
AA
2


A
2024-01-01
AB
1


A
2024-01-02
AA
1


B
2024-01-01
AA
1


B
2024-01-01
AB
3


B - target
2024-01-01
AB
2


B
2024-01-02
AA
2


B - target
2024-01-02
AA
1


C
2024-01-02
AA
2



In other words, some of the product B (these in sector = Y) need to be counted twice - first time as part of B products and one more time as "B - target", because they are part of sector = Y
I tried to create the view using the following query:
SELECT 
product,
date,
subproduct,
count(*)
FROM table a
GROUP BY product, date, subproduct 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
'B - target' as product,
date,
subproduct,
count(*)
FROM table a
WHERE product = 'B' and sector = 'Y'
GROUP BY product, date, subproduct 

But I receive the the message that in BigQuery I can't target the same table twice in incremental materialized view.
I tried with CASE
CASE
WHEN product = 'B' and sector = 'Y' THEN 'B -target'
ELSE product 
END AS product 

But this time they are not included in the total B count.
Any ideas if there is a workaround?

I don't know the limitations of BigQuery, but you can use a CTE to refer to a table just once and use it multiple times:
with cte as (
    select * from table
)
SELECT 
    product,
    date,
    subproduct,
    count(*)
FROM cte a
GROUP BY product, date, subproduct 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'B - target' as product,
    date,
    subproduct,
    count(*)
FROM cte a
WHERE product = 'B' and sector = 'Y'
GROUP BY product, date, subproduct 


Unfortunately I'm getting 'Incremental materialized view query contains unsupported features.' when tried CTE approach.
